# Responsive Website using Descendant Selector

Tags: html, css, responsive

im trying to make my website responsive using media queries, however the page is not responding when i used the descendant selector in certain parts of me code.

The page is responsive when i use this code:

```
.div1{
  float: left;
  width:20%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:red;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  margin-left: 2%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


.div2{
   float: left;
   width:20%;
   height: 200px;
   background-color:yellow;
   border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
   margin-left: 2%;
   border-radius: 50%;
   }



 .div3{
     float: left;
     width:20%;
     border-radius: 50%;
     height: 200px;
     background-color:blue;
     border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
     margin-left: 2%;
     }



  /* media queries*/
   @media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .sec1 div{
   width:40% ;

    }
   }
```

whenever i use this code, the page is longer responsive:

```
.sec1 .div1{
  float: left;
  width:20%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:red;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  margin-left: 2%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


.sec1 .div2{
   float: left;
   width:20%;
   height: 200px;
   background-color:yellow;
   border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
   margin-left: 2%;
   border-radius: 50%;
   }



 .sec1 .div3{
     float: left;
     width:20%;
     border-radius: 50%;
     height: 200px;
     background-color:blue;
     border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
     margin-left: 2%;
     }



  /* media queries*/
   @media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .sec1 div{
   width:40% ;

    }
   }
```

My HTML:

```
 <body>
     <div class="sec1">
       <div class="div1">
       </div>

       <div class="div2">
       </div>

       <div class="div3">

       </div>
   </div>
 <body/>
```

Notice the difference bewteen the codes is the addition of the class sec1 before the div classes (before the media query). My question is, why doesn't the latter code work?

Comment: specificity issue

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. If you want to add info to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50542256/1016716), edit the question instead of creating a new one. Also, the end tag for the body has a typo, but I don't think that influences things.